# How do I see how many purchases/downloads I've had for my Windows Phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, app-store, analytics

Does anyone know how you see how many downloads/purchases of your Windows Phone 7 app you've had?

The reports in the App Hub don't show me a anything!

Cheers,
Ash.

Comment: Understood, are there any other stackexchange sites this question would be relevant for? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Other than AppHub you can use the Microsoft-endorsed solution called [Runtime Intelligence Service](http://www.preemptive.com/windowsphone7.html). According to their website:

> Application monitoring and
>   analytics
>
> - Number of application sessions
> - Number of unique users
> - Feature usage counts and duration
> - General system and stability statistics